# Get results for all rows

Tags: javascript, php

I have a query running in json.
Inside the shopping cart page when the number button is hit
I just want the price to be multiplied by the number of rows

```
$result->execute();
$results=$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($results as $row) {
  if ($row['darsad_price_offer'] == '') {
    $prices = $row['price'];
  } else {
    $prices = $row['price_offer'];
  }
  $tedad = $row['tedadmahsol'];
  $pricerow2 = $prices * $tedad;
}
return [$results,$pricerow];

var pricerow=response[3];
$(".basketrows.activedel").find('.pricejson').html(pricerow);
```

Comment: It may be worth doing this in the SQL if you can.

Comment: Why not just using `echo json_encode $results;`

Comment: This would generally done faster by doing so in the SQL instead of PHP. `SELEC price, item_name, item_price, COUNT(id) * item_price as total_price.....` or something to that effect. without the current query / the table setup it's hard to guess